# Simple application of Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Q) Let $\mu$ be a positive measure defined on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f\in L^1(\mu)$, then

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} fd\mu = \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{[-R,R]} fd\mu$$

My attempt: I mean $$\int_{[-R,R]} fd\mu = \int f.1_{[-R,R]}d\mu$$

and somehow the limit is taken inside. $f.1_{[-R,R]}$ need not be dominated by $f$ so I don't know how to find an integrable function that dominates $f.1_{[-R,R]}$ and not sure how to use that $\mu$ is a positive measure?

Comment: Are you using Rudin? If you split the function up into the sum of its negative and positive parts, then you can show that each part can be explained by DCT, and then use the fact that the sum of the integrals is the same as the integral of the sum....if you're still confused let me know and I can try to write out a more complete answer!

Comment: @Chair, I see, so $f=f^+ - f^-$ and since $f\in L^1$, we have $f^+ \in L^1$ and $f.1_{[-R,R]} \leq f^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You have the exact right idea! Remember what the DCT says

> If $f_n \to f$ and for some $g \in L^1$, each $|f_n| \leq g$, then
> $\lim \int f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu$

Now we use your idea of taking $f_n = f \cdot \chi_{[-n,n]}$. All that's left is to show that $|f_n| \leq g$ for some $g \in L^1$. Do you see why?

Of course, we know that $|f_n| \leq |f|$... Can you show that $|f| \in L^1$? Can you finish the proof from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^